# I am making a snake game in java and am trying to make it so it shows the user's high score

Tags: java

I am trying to update my "HighScore.txt" file with the applesEaten variable if it surpasses the number that is already in the "HighScore.txt" file.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 600;
    static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int UNIT_SIZE = 25;
    static final int GAME_UNITS = (SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT) / UNIT_SIZE;
    static final int DELAY = 75;
    final int x[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    final int y[] = new int[GAME_UNITS];
    int bodyParts = 6;
    int applesEaten;
    int highScore = 0;
    int prevHighScore;
    int appleX;
    int appleY;
    char direction = 'R';
    boolean running = false;
    Timer timer;
    Random random;
    
    GamePanel() {
        random = new Random();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
        startGame();
    }
    
    public void startGame() {
        newApple();
        running = true;
        timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        draw(g);
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        
        if (running) {
            /*
            for (int i = 0; i < SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE; i++) {
                g.drawLine(i * UNIT_SIZE, 0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
                g.drawLine(0, i * UNIT_SIZE, SCREEN_WIDTH, i * UNIT_SIZE);
            }
            */
            
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(appleX, appleY, UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < bodyParts; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                }
                else {
                    g.setColor(new Color(45, 180, 0));
                    //g.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)));
                    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], UNIT_SIZE, UNIT_SIZE);
                }
            }
            
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont(new Font("Ink Free", Font.BOLD, 40));
            FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            g.drawString("Score: " + applesEaten, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics.stringWidth("Score: " + applesEaten)) / 2, g.getFont().getSize());
        }
        else {
            gameOver(g);
        }
    }
    
    public void newApple() {
        appleX = random.nextInt((int)(SCREEN_WIDTH / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
        appleY = random.nextInt((int)(SCREEN_HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE)) * UNIT_SIZE;
    }
    
    public void move() {
        for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
            x[i] = x[i-1];
            y[i] = y[i-1];
        }
        
        switch(direction) {
        case 'U':
            y[0] = y[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
            
        case 'D':
            y[0] = y[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
            
        case 'L':
            x[0] = x[0] - UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
            
        case 'R':
            x[0] = x[0] + UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
            
        }
    }
    
    public void checkApple() {
        
        if ((x[0] == appleX) && (y[0] == appleY)) {
            bodyParts++;
            applesEaten++;
            newApple();
        }
    }
    
    public int highScoreChecker() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileInputStream fileByteStream = null;
        Scanner inFS = null;
        
        try {
            
            fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("HighScore.txt");
            inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
            
            prevHighScore = inFS.nextInt();
        } 
        
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if (applesEaten > prevHighScore) {
            try {
                FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("HighScore.txt");
                myWriter.write(applesEaten + "");
                myWriter.close();
                
                inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);
                highScore = inFS.nextInt();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        else {
            highScore = prevHighScore;
        }
        
        return highScore;
    }
```

If I put the number 3 in the file and get to only 2 apples eaten then end the game by running into the wall the game properly outputs my score for that round (2) and then the high score of 3 that I put into "HighScore.txt". However, if I were to surpass 3 then the game would crash and I would get these errors.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at GamePanel.highScoreChecker(GamePanel.java:138)
    at GamePanel.gameOver(GamePanel.java:203)
    at GamePanel.draw(GamePanel.java:84)
    at GamePanel.paintComponent(GamePanel.java:50)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1119)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5311)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1657)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1570)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1337)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5259)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5069)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:879)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:862)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:862)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:835)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1898)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: You need to close the scanner/filestream each time you're done reading from it, and then recreate it when you need to read from it again. You're not doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issue I see is that you are not resetting the fileByteStream before reading from it again to get the updated high score. After writing the high score to the file, you need to close the stream and then reopen it before reading from it again.